# Причины по которым Type.GetFields() может возвращать пустой массив

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть класс AccessTypes:

```
public class AccessTypes
{   
    public AccessTypes() 
    {
        Friends = 1;
        All = 2;
        Marked = 3;
    }

    public int Friends { get; set; }
    public int All { get; set; }
    public int Marked { get; set; }
}
```

Есть метод ASP.NET MVC контроллера:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetAccessSettings")]
public IActionResult GetAccessSettings()
{
    AccessTypes AccessTypes = new AccessTypes();

    return Ok(AccessTypes.GetType().GetFields()[0].Name); // Тут возникает исключение
}
```

Возникает исключение:
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Как бы я не старался вытянуть поля из экземпляра класса AccessTypes, метод GetFields() всегда возвращает пустой массив. Раньше метод работал безотказно на сущностях для Entity Framework или *.dto.cs объектах, но сейчас, когда класс был создан мной, метод отказывается работать. Может нужно прописывать какие то декораторы или особым образом называть поля класса? Совсем не понимаю куда копать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

метод [`Type.GetFields`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.getfields?view=net-7.0), при вызове без параметров, возвращает **публичные** поля.

В приведенном коде публичных полей нет. Поэтому ничего и не возвращается.

---

Вместо полей в коде в вопросе используются **свойства**. Для их получения нужно воспользоваться методом [`Type.GetProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=net-8.0)

Comment: Но ведь я прописал полям модификатор доступа public. Возможно речь идет не про модификаторы доступа. Как в таком случае мне их сделать публичными?

Comment: @ДмитрийГавшин, добавил пояснение в ответ.